# Unable to copy large file onto ext2 usb stick

Tags: linux, disk-usage, usb-drive, disk

I have an 8G usb stick (I'm on linux Mint), and I'm trying to copy a 5.4G file into it, but getting

```
No space left on device
```

The filesize of the copied file before failing is always 3.6G

An output of the mounted stick shows..

```
df -T
/dev/sdc1      ext2       7708584    622604   6694404   9% /media/moo/ba20d7ab-2c46-4f7a-9fb8-baa0ee71e9fe

df -h
/dev/sdc1       7.4G  608M  6.4G   9% /media/moo/ba20d7ab-2c46-4f7a-9fb8-baa0ee71e9fe

du -h --max-depth=1
88K ./.ssh

ls -h myfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 moo moo 5.4G May 26 09:35 myfile
```

So a 5.4G file, won't seem to go on an 8G usb stick. I thought there wasn't issues with ext2, and it was only problems with fat32 for file sizes and usb sticks ? Would changing the formatting make any difference ?

Edit: Here is an report from tunefs for the drive

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdd1
```

Filesystem volume name:   
Last mounted on:          /media/moo/ba20d7ab-2c46-4f7a-9fb8-baa0ee71e9fe
Filesystem UUID:          ba20d7ab-2c46-4f7a-9fb8-baa0ee71e9fe
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         not clean with errors
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              489600
Block count:              1957884
Reserved block count:     97894
Free blocks:              970072
Free inodes:              489576
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      477
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Filesystem created:       Mon Mar  2 13:00:18 2009
Last mount time:          Tue May 26 12:12:59 2015
Last write time:          Tue May 26 12:12:59 2015
Mount count:              102
Maximum mount count:      26
Last checked:             Mon Mar  2 13:00:18 2009
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sat Aug 29 14:00:18 2009
Lifetime writes:          12 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      249823e2-d3c4-4f17-947c-3500523479fd
FS Error count:           62
First error time:         Tue May 26 09:48:15 2015
First error function:     ext4_mb_generate_buddy
First error line #:       757
First error inode #:      0
First error block #:      0
Last error time:          Tue May 26 10:35:25 2015
Last error function:      ext4_mb_generate_buddy
Last error line #:        757
Last error inode #:       0
Last error block #:       0

Comment: Could it be that you or your tools are confused about GB versus GiB? And since it is ext2, how much of the space is reserved for root (by default this is 5%).

Comment: Thanks, how can I tell how much of the space is reserved ?

Comment: @Ian To display file system information, use: `tune2fs -l /dev/<device>`

Comment: Thanks, I have added an output from tunefs for the mounted device. I note the not clean/errors, just looking at that

Comment: Your file system has errors. Run `fsck` on the file system and inspect/delete the contents of `lost+found`. Also note that 385MiB are reserved for root (97894 blocks). You might want to adjust that value with `tune2fs`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this now works. umount and sudo e2fsck  /dev/sdd1 seems to have fixed it (had multiply-claimed block errors, maybe from previous failures as it mentioned same filename). If you want to set it as an answer, will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your 8GB stick has approximately 7.5 GiB and even with some file system overhead should be able to store the 5.4GiB file.

You use `tune2fs` to check the file sytem status and properties:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/<device>
```

By default 5% of the space is reserved for the root user. Your output lists 97894 blocks, which corresponds to approximately 385MiB and seems to be the default value. You might want to adjust this value using `tune2fs` if you don't need that much reserved space. Nevertheless, even with those 385MiB the file should fit on the file system.

Your `tune2fs` output shows an unclean file system with errors. So please run `fsck` on the file system. This will fix the errors and possibly place some files in the `lost+found` directory. You can delete them if you're not intending to recover the data.

This should fix the file system and copying the file will succeed.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, I know I'm a Windows user, not a linux user, but I had a similar issue a while ago when trying to copy files to a 16Gig data stick, to transfer to and from an old laptop.  As it turned out, most of the file system formats for removable devices (ext2, fat32 etc), don't support copying files if the file is greater than 3.2Gigs in size, because of some default space usually being reserved for root and system files etc... I usually got an error telling me the drive was full (even though it was totally empty and freshly formatted).

After doing some research, I found out that the NTFS file system is best for transferring large files from system to stick, as it is the only file system that allows files larger than 3.2 to be copied without any issues.

Don't know if this will be of any help, but it's always a possible solution.

Comment: unfortunately for you ext2 [actually *does* support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) such big files and besides the limit for FAT32 is 2 GiB without LFS, 4 GiB with and 256 GiB with FAT32+ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)).